# Discord.py - AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Embed'

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I have been receiving an error when trying to use discord.Embed on my Discord Bot.

> 2018-09-16T15:46:20.254940+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in command dave
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.256521+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265538+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265541+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265590+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "bot.py", line 83, in dave
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265592+00:00 app[worker.1]:     embed = discord.Embed(title=data['output'], colour=discord.Colour(0x99cc))
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265669+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Embed'
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265720+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265722+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265723+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265765+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265840+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 822, in process_commands
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265842+00:00 app[worker.1]:     yield from command.invoke(ctx)
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265885+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 367, in invoke
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265887+00:00 app[worker.1]:     yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265928+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 52, in wrapped
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265930+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
>   2018-09-16T15:46:20.265995+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Embed'

Was the full output in the console.

My relevant code is as follows:

````
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import json
import random
import requests

client = Bot(description="My Bot", command_prefix="~")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def dave(ctx, *, query = ""):
    ''' Talks to Dave '''

    if query == "":
        await client.say("Sample usage: ```~dave Hello```")
    else:
        r = requests.get('https://example.com/dave/api.php?discord=' + str(ctx.message.author.id) + '&query=' + str(query))
        data = r.json()
        data = json.dumps(data)
        data = json.loads(data)

        if data['status'] == "unknown":
            unsure = ["I don't know how to do that yet.", "Hmm... I am unsure.", "Sorry, you appear to have confused me.", "I don't know how to help you with that."]
            await client.say(random.choice(unsure))
            return

        embed = discord.Embed(title=data['output'], colour=discord.Colour(0x99cc))

        if data['discordAction'] != None:
            embed.set_image(url=data['discordAction'])

        embed.set_author(name="Dave", url="https://example.com/dave/", icon_url="https://example.com/Storage_new/2018/small/dave-small.png")
        embed.set_footer(text="Powered by Dave", icon_url="https://example.com/drive/uploads/1/bv3gfc333mceuaqw8jlpyrnrfiqi7r/f73h4m12qdxl45n.png")
        await client.say(embed=embed)

client.run('intentionally removed')
````

The file is also called `bot.py`. The code has been changed to example instead of my actual domains and so on. All the code worked until I introduced the `discord.Embed` part.

Comment: do you perhaps have a file called `discord.py` in your cwd?

Comment: @MCO no, there is no file named `discord.py`

Comment: Try opening up an interactive python shell, in the same directory you would normally run your bot from, and running `import discord; print(discord.__file__)`.  That should give you some idea of where in your computer Python is getting the discord package from.

Answer (score 2):

> All the code worked until I introduced the discord.Embed part.

I think I know why...it might be outdated.

Here, try using the following command:
`pip install --upgrade discord.py`

Comment: `$ pip3 install --upgrade discord.py
    Requirement already up-to-date: discord.py in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (0.16.12)
    ...`

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is that you need to import embeds, this is what I did to fix it:`from discord import Embed`